# Class AB amplifier becomes hotter, using more current and then becoming even hotter

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt, heat, thermal

[image]
In the circuit above a Class AB amplifier (this is one also called Class A+AB) can be seen with Q1 and Q3 used to get the current biasing voltage for Q2 and Q4. transistors Q2 and Q4 become hotter and hotter and requiring more and more current in the actual built circuit and in the end it reduces the output signal to 0. Are there easy changes that can be made to prevent this from happing?
The power supply gives 10Volt.

EDIT: As some of you noticed, there's was no resistor shown at the output in the figure above,  but it is added now.

Comment: The first obvious problem is that the collector of Q1 should be connected to the collector of Q4, exactly the same way that the collector of Q3 is connected to the collector of Q2.  But the whole circuit looks wrong somehow - I'm going to need to look at it closer.

Comment: @DwayneReid The collector of Q3 and Q4 are both connected to ground.

Comment: It's overbiassed. I would have expected to see emitter resistors for Q2 and Q4 of around 0R1 to 0R33 each, and some NFB too. Strange circuit. There are plenty of good ones. I would start again.

Comment: Small emitter resistors are the usual practise for output transistors

Comment: @EJP Andy_aka Yes, there was indeed a small resistor connected at the output, but it was not shown in the figure above.

Comment: So *show* it in the figure above. Your description is just ambiguous. However it sounds like a Zobel network shunting the output. Where did you get this from?

Comment: Ok so the cap is a coupling cap, probably 4700uF in real life, and the 10R represents the speaker load.

Comment: @EJP Now it is shown in the figure above. I don't know what how a ' Zobel network shunting the output' is related to this, could you explain that and if you think there's a way to fix the heating and shutting down problem, please? Yes, a coupling cap and a speaker load at the output.

Comment: A Zobel network shunting the output isn't relevant to this. It was my first guess at what you meant because your description was ambiguous. The way to fix this is to reduce the bias, which I've already stated, and the best way to achieve that is to throw this away and use a better circuit, as everybody has already stated. I would be looking for a circuit with emitter resistors, and a bias-spreader transistor with an adjustment pot. There's no shortage.

Comment: I'm also wondering what the rail voltage is. If it isn't 10 volts, twice the unmodulated input signal level, it won't work. This whole question is a demonstration of how it can be futile to post a partial schematic.

Comment: @EJP reducing which bias? The bias current or bias voltage of which point of which transistor? The power supply does indeed give 10 Volts.

Comment: The bias current through the non-existent emitter resistors. If you must persist, fit 0R33 between the emitter of Q2 and the output cap; same for Q4; and increase the values of the 39ohm resistors. You should measure 10-20mV across both emitter rspesistors in series. Orders of magnitude more than that is too much. In any event you need to add some NFB. And a Zobel network, 10R in series with 100nF from the junction of the emitter resistors to ground. I still agree with everybody else that there is something seriously wrong with this circuit. For the 3rd or 4th time, where did you get it?

Comment: Or else it's class A and you need to add some serious heat sinking.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using the B-E junctions of Q1 and Q3 to provide the bias for Q2 and Q4, respectively. This will only work if the four transistors are coupled thermally so that they are all at the same temperature.

Also, the value of 39 for RES1 and RES2 is ridiculously low. What are the operating voltages of this amplifier?

Overall, this is a very poor circuit. Where did you get it?

Comment: Does that mean glueing those transistors together? Will that work with those power transistors? The input and output voltage is around 5V DC with an amplitude of around 3V. So the signal goes from 2V until 8V

Comment: No, don't glue them together. First, get a better circuit to work with.

Comment: So you think there is not an easy way to fix this circuit?

Comment: Power supply gives 10V.